# Hibernate/JPA @AttributeOverrides not playing nicely with Groovy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, groovy

**Please note:** full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and reproducible source code is [here on my GitHub repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/groovy-hibernate-annotations). Like the README says, just clone and run `./gradlew clean build` to reproduce the error that I'm seeing.

---

I'm designing the data model for a **Groovy** (not Java) Spring Boot app that will use Hibernate/JPA to read/write entities to/from MySQL. All of my entities will extend an abstract `BaseEntity` which provides a PK as well as another identifier ("`refId`"). For instance:

```
@Canonical
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity {
  @Id
  Long id

  String refId
}

@Canonical
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="customer_id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column=@Column(name="customer_ref_id"))
})
class Customer extends BaseEntity {
  @Column(name = "customer_name")
  String name

  @Column(name = "customer_fav_food")
  String favoriteFood
}
```

As you can see, because each entity extends `BaseEntity`, and because I want each subclass/entity/table to have its own column name for the `id` and `refId` fields, I need to use that `AttributeOverrides` declaration in each subclass.

However `AttributeOverrides` is causing a compiler issue that I can't reproduce in plain ole' Java. At compile-time it complains with an `unexpected token` error at `n=@Column(name="customer_id")),`.

Can anyone reproduce and figure out what's going on (and what the fix is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However AttributeOverrides is causing a compiler issue that I can't reproduce in plain ole' Java.

Unlike Java's compiler, Groovy's  compiler takes `{ ... }` as a [Closure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) instead of an Array. You should use `[ ... ]` instead, just like this:

```
@Canonical
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides([
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="customer_id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column=@Column(name="customer_ref_id"))
])
class Customer extends BaseEntity {
    // ...    
}
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Thanks so much!